# Game of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots

> Written on a blackboard is the polynomial: $$x^2+x+2014$$  Calvin and Peter take turns alternately in the following game:
>
> During his turn, Calvin must either increase or decrease the coefficient of $x$ by $1$.  (Calvin's turn comes first.)
>
> Then, for Peter's turn, he must either increase or decrease the constant coefficient by $1$.
>
> Calvin wins if at any point the polynomial currently written on the blackboard has integer roots (regardless of whose turn it is at that time.)
>
> Prove that Calvin has a winning strategy.

I came across this problem today in INMO (Indian National Mathematical Olympiad).

I considered the three cases that Peter either continuously decreases, continuously increases, or keeps the constant term in the vicinity of 2014 by alternatively increasing and decreasing the constant term.

If he decreases, then eventually the constant term equals zero and we get integer roots.

If he increases to a max of $t$ units after $t$ turns, then so does Calvin, and we get the polynomial $x^2+tx+2014+t$.  Setting its discriminant greater than zero gives us the range of $t$ for which real solutions are obtained.  After that, clearly we will get some integer $t+n$ such that the root is an integer, as the numerator only has to be an even number for this to happen.

The third case follows trivially as a subset of the second case.

Is my approach valid?  Are there other approaches?

Comment: Where did you come across this problem?  What've you tried?  This smells suspiciously like a contest problem.

Comment: You start by collecting some useful facts. Perhaps notation first: At any time in the game, the polynomial is $x^2+cx+p$. (Calvin controls $c$, Peter controls $p$.) Write down the condition for integer roots in terms of $c$, $p$. Then try to think of what Calvin can do to force the condition to be true.

Comment: It sounds more like brilliant.org...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Calvin can always reach a quadratic like $x^2+(a+2)x+2a$. Peter can change the constant term only by $1$, while Calvin can move to his target constant effectively at twice the speed by varying $a$.

Also show that at close quarters, say when the sum is nearly half, with a little care, Calvin can always force a win.

Comment: +1 Aiming for $2p-q=4$ is indeed much simpler than aiming for $p^2-4q$ to become a perfect square (or $5$) as I was about to write down.